# Installing NPM - missing script: start

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-init

I'm currently having problems starting NPM. I've installed along with Node.JS.

When I Run 'npm start' via Command Prompt I recieve the following ...

C:\Users\bobbyy>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bobby\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-03-29T21_36_56_974Z-debug.log

Can someone please advise what should be in 'package.json' start?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue do you mind adding the log file and check if the start script is in your `package.json` file or not

Comment: Can you paste your ´package.json´ file and also, do you have a ´index.js´ or ´server.js´ file to start your project? If you have a ´server.js´ try with ´npm start server.js´

Answer (score 0):

Write a code in package.json file as below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Copied from [github forum](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/411)
Hope It works for you.